# Expression for 'beating or stopping a hole in ground and another one appears?

Tags: phrase-requests

I have seen this in many cartoons, where the farmer tries to shut one hole in garden so his veggies are not stolen but another one appears and so on and so forth. One of the most obvious example of these are bugs bunny animation movies, where bugs after eating all the veggies asks the farmer 'What's up doc. ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**whack-a-mole**  [macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/whack-a-mole)

fig. a situation in which repeated efforts to resolve a problem are frustrated by the problem reappearing in a different form

As in:

> “If you are on the back end, you are kind of playing whack-a-mole
>   trying to pick this up,” one bank source told me. Submitted from
>   United Kingdom on 03/01/2018

Comment: Of course, likely more people associate "whack-a-mole" with the arcade game than with holes in the ground.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoP1E9J4jpg

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the phrase is used explicitly  as a reference to the game, as it was used in the example you showed. You'd say "This garden is like a game of whack-a-mole," not "This garden is whack-a-mole."

Comment: @Karen Yeah, and it's a user-submitted definition from 5 months ago. Not sure how many people know or use this figurative meaning.

Comment: I hear "playing whack-a-mole" all the time in the US. The phrase is derived from a [physical arcade game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whac-A-Mole). It was even reimplemented as a [virtual mini-game inside World of Warcraft](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Whack-a-Gnoll-an-arcade-style-reaction-game-in-WoW_fig1_260981482). I would expect it to be well known in both AmE and BrE.

Comment: Yes, it's a very common metaphor for any situation where new problems keep arising as you solve previous problems. It does derive from the game.